# Swift Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: json, swift

I am facing some issues when mapping my JSON response to the model. After getting the error printed it says the 'type mismatch' although I created a model class from quicktype.io. Here is my model class. I have read many questions about the same title, but I dont find any help.

```
// This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let responseCustomerInfiormation = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(ResponseCustomerInfiormation.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

// MARK: - ResponseCustomerInfiormation
class ResponseCustomerInfiormation: Codable {
    let status: Bool?
    let message: String?
    let responseDescription: ResponseDescription?
    let encryptStatus: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "Status"
        case message = "Message"
        case responseDescription = "ResponseDescription"
        case encryptStatus = "EncryptStatus"
    }

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self,forKey: .status)
        message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self,forKey: .message)
        responseDescription = try values.decodeIfPresent(ResponseDescription.self,forKey: .responseDescription)
        encryptStatus = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .encryptStatus)

    }

    class ResponseDescription: Codable {
        let id: Int?
        let customerWebID: Int?
        let customerWalletID: Int?
        let cellNo: String?
        let firstName: String?
        let lastName: String?
        let dateOfBirth: String?
        let pincode: String?
        let password: String?
        let cnic: String?
        let emiratesExpiry: String?
        let email: String?
        let walletCard: String?
        let kkCard: String?
        let country: String?
        let countryID: Int?
        let countryOfBirth: String?
        let homeCountryCellNo: String?
        let city: String?
        let cityID: Int?
        let residentOrVisitor: Int?
        let nationalityID: Int?
        let nationality: String?
        let profilePicture: String?
        let regionID: Int?
        let address: String?
        let themeColor: Int?
        let vendorID: Int?
        let vendorImage: String?
        let sahulatWallet: String?
        let karachiKingWallet: String?
        let qrCode: String?
        let valueBack: String?
        let promotionalValueBack: String?
        let aryCoin: String?
        let lockedTopup: String?
        let sahulatComitiAmount: String?
        let sonaComitiAmount: String?
        let sonaComitiGold: String?
        let milliGoldRedeemable: String?
        let milliGoldUnRedeemable: String?
        let milliGoldAmountUnRedeemable: String?
        let sahulatWalletCardRegistrationFeePaid: String?
        let karachiKingCardRegistrationFeePaid: String?
        let totalMonthlyFeeDueSahulatCard: String?
        let totalMonthlyFeeDueKKCard: String?
        let totalMonthlyFeePaid: String?
        let totalMonthlyFeeDue: String?
        let dollarDealPurchaseAmount: String?
        let dollarDealValueBack: String?
        let dollarDealPromotionalValueBack: String?
        let tokenNo: String?
        let encryptionKey: String?
        let responseStatus: Bool?
        let responseMessage: String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id = "ID"
            case customerWebID = "CustomerWebID"
            case customerWalletID = "CustomerWalletID"
            case cellNo = "CellNo"
            case firstName = "FirstName"
            case lastName = "LastName"
            case dateOfBirth = "DateOfBirth"
            case pincode = "Pincode"
            case password = "Password"
            case cnic = "CNIC"
            case emiratesExpiry = "EmiratesExpiry"
            case email = "Email"
            case walletCard = "WalletCard"
            case kkCard = "KKCard"
            case country = "Country"
            case countryID = "CountryID"
            case countryOfBirth = "CountryOfBirth"
            case homeCountryCellNo = "HomeCountryCellNo"
            case city = "City"
            case cityID = "CityID"
            case residentOrVisitor = "ResidentOrVisitor"
            case nationalityID = "NationalityID"
            case nationality = "Nationality"
            case profilePicture = "ProfilePicture"
            case regionID = "RegionID"
            case address = "Address"
            case themeColor = "ThemeColor"
            case vendorID = "VendorID"
            case vendorImage = "VendorImage"
            case sahulatWallet = "SahulatWallet"
            case karachiKingWallet = "KarachiKingWallet"
            case qrCode = "QRCode"
            case valueBack = "ValueBack"
            case promotionalValueBack = "PromotionalValueBack"
            case aryCoin = "ARYCoin"
            case lockedTopup = "LockedTopup"
            case sahulatComitiAmount = "SahulatComitiAmount"
            case sonaComitiAmount = "SonaComitiAmount"
            case sonaComitiGold = "SonaComitiGold"
            case milliGoldRedeemable = "MilliGoldRedeemable"
            case milliGoldUnRedeemable = "MilliGoldUnRedeemable"
            case milliGoldAmountUnRedeemable = "MilliGoldAmountUnRedeemable"
            case sahulatWalletCardRegistrationFeePaid = "SahulatWalletCardRegistrationFeePaid"
            case karachiKingCardRegistrationFeePaid = "KarachiKingCardRegistrationFeePaid"
            case totalMonthlyFeeDueSahulatCard = "TotalMonthlyFeeDueSahulatCard"
            case totalMonthlyFeeDueKKCard = "TotalMonthlyFeeDueKKCard"
            case totalMonthlyFeePaid = "TotalMonthlyFeePaid"
            case totalMonthlyFeeDue = "TotalMonthlyFeeDue"
            case dollarDealPurchaseAmount = "DollarDealPurchaseAmount"
            case dollarDealValueBack = "DollarDealValueBack"
            case dollarDealPromotionalValueBack = "DollarDealPromotionalValueBack"
            case tokenNo = "TokenNo"
            case encryptionKey = "EncryptionKey"
            case responseStatus = "ResponseStatus"
            case responseMessage = "ResponseMessage"
        }

        required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

            id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
            customerWebID = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .customerWebID)
            customerWalletID = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .customerWalletID)
            cellNo = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .cellNo)
            firstName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
            lastName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
            dateOfBirth = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .dateOfBirth)
            pincode = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .pincode)
            password = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .password)
            cnic = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .cnic)
            emiratesExpiry = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .emiratesExpiry)
            email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
            walletCard = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .walletCard)
            kkCard = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .kkCard)
            country = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .country)
            countryID = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .countryID)
            countryOfBirth = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .countryOfBirth)
            homeCountryCellNo = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .homeCountryCellNo)
            city = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .city)


            cityID = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .cityID)
            residentOrVisitor = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .residentOrVisitor)
            nationalityID = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .nationalityID)
            nationality = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .nationality)
            profilePicture = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .profilePicture)
            regionID = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .regionID)
            address = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .address)
            themeColor = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .themeColor)
            vendorID = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .vendorID)
            vendorImage = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .vendorImage)
            sahulatWallet = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .sahulatWallet)
            karachiKingWallet = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .karachiKingWallet)
             qrCode = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .qrCode)
            valueBack = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .valueBack)
            promotionalValueBack = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .promotionalValueBack)
            aryCoin = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .aryCoin)
            lockedTopup = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lockedTopup)
            sahulatComitiAmount = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .sahulatComitiAmount)
            sonaComitiAmount = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .sonaComitiAmount)
            sonaComitiGold = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .sonaComitiGold)
            milliGoldRedeemable = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .milliGoldRedeemable)
            milliGoldUnRedeemable = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .milliGoldUnRedeemable)
            milliGoldAmountUnRedeemable = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .milliGoldAmountUnRedeemable)
            sahulatWalletCardRegistrationFeePaid = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .sahulatWalletCardRegistrationFeePaid)
            karachiKingCardRegistrationFeePaid = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .karachiKingCardRegistrationFeePaid)

            totalMonthlyFeeDueSahulatCard = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .totalMonthlyFeeDueSahulatCard)
            totalMonthlyFeeDueKKCard = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .totalMonthlyFeeDueKKCard)
            totalMonthlyFeePaid = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .totalMonthlyFeePaid)
            totalMonthlyFeeDue = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .totalMonthlyFeeDue)
            dollarDealPurchaseAmount = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .dollarDealPurchaseAmount)
            dollarDealValueBack = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .dollarDealValueBack)
            dollarDealPromotionalValueBack = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .dollarDealPromotionalValueBack)
            tokenNo = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .tokenNo)
            encryptionKey = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .encryptionKey)
            responseStatus = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .responseStatus)
            responseMessage = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .responseMessage)
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - ResponseDescription
```

And the JSON I am receiving is

```
{
  "Status": true,
  "Message": "Customer Information Found",
  "ResponseDescription": {
    "ID": 11111,
    "CustomerWebID": 324,
    "CustomerWalletID": 1234,
    "CellNo": "",
    "FirstName": "mujtuba",
    "LastName": " Amin",
    "DateOfBirth": "19000-01-01",
    "Pincode": "8120",
    "Password": "",
    "CNIC": "",
    "EmiratesExpiry": "",
    "Email": "",
    "WalletCard": "",
    "KKCard": "",
    "Country": "United Arab Emirates",
    "CountryID": 0,
    "CountryOfBirth": "",
    "HomeCountryCellNo": "00",
    "City": "",
    "CityID": 0,
    "ResidentOrVisitor": 1,
    "NationalityID": 0,
    "Nationality": "Pakistani",
    "ProfilePicture": " ",
    "RegionID": 2,
    "Address": "dd",
    "ThemeColor": 0,
    "VendorID": 0,
    "VendorImage": "",
    "SahulatWallet": "1",
    "KarachiKingWallet": "0",
    "QRCode": "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=400x400&cht=qr&chld=h&chl=970657|2|2345|941A3E84-B1EB-4B9B-9141-71227844A5B9",
    "ValueBack": "3",
    "PromotionalValueBack": "3",
    "ARYCoin": "1000",
    "LockedTopup": "0",
    "SahulatComitiAmount": "0",
    "SonaComitiAmount": "0",
    "SonaComitiGold": "0",
    "MilliGoldRedeemable": "3656",
    "MilliGoldUnRedeemable": "0",
    "MilliGoldAmountUnRedeemable": "0",
    "SahulatWalletCardRegistrationFeePaid": "0",
    "KarachiKingCardRegistrationFeePaid": "0",
    "TotalMonthlyFeeDueSahulatCard": "0",
    "TotalMonthlyFeeDueKKCard": "0",
    "TotalMonthlyFeePaid": "0",
    "TotalMonthlyFeeDue": "0",
    "DollarDealPurchaseAmount": "0",
    "DollarDealValueBack": "0",
    "DollarDealPromotionalValueBack": "0",
    "TokenNo": "0",
    "EncryptionKey": "",
    "ResponseStatus": true,
    "ResponseMessage": "Customer Details Found"
  },
  "EncryptStatus": true
}
```

Can anyone please guide me that where I am having error or which part of code is making issue.

Comment: I just ran your JSON through a JSON validator, and found that the line `"CustomerWalletID":0000,` has an invalid number. `0000` should have been `0` or `"0000"`. Can you change the code that produces the JSON?

Comment: I am not going to read through all that code, please make sure you print as detailed error as possible by doing `do { ... } catch { print(error) }` when decoding and then update your question with the error message. The error you get this way is detailed and very helpful

Comment: *"Number with leading zero around character 158."* - This would lead me to believe Sweepers comment

Comment: Changing `"CustomerWalletID": 0000,` to `"CustomerWalletID": 0,` fixes the problem for me

Comment: I always receive "CustomerWalletID" as an Int. The server sends unique id to all customers. Like 2345, 4325 etc. 
Is there any particular error in the model or Swift is right that its a type mismatch?

Comment: Why can’t you include a proper error message like I requested?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The error states : The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
And in error window it says "Type mismatch"

Comment: Is that the error from the actual decoding, `JSONDecoder.decode(...)` and if so did you follow my instructions?

Comment: The actual problem is the server. A numeric value with leading zero is invalid, period. Ask the owner of the service to fix the issue on the server.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson . 
typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "ResponseDescription", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: I do not get any error with the posted json and code. Have you changed your class defintion?

Comment: Can I send you my base controller code?

Answer (score 0):

your json response is not in correct format.

```
"CustomerWalletID": 0000 // this is causing problem
"CustomerWalletID": 0, // try this
```

Reference :- [This will show you if your json is valid or not](https://jsonformatter.org)

Comment: I also tried this as pointed by some friends above. But still, it says the data format is not correct. Although this service is working correctly in Android

Comment: ask backend developer not to send 0000

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with initializer I guess, do try this type of initializer

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    ...
}
```

Comment: update initializer of `ResponseCustomerInfiormation`

Comment: This is no problem with the initializer, the problem is caused by the wrong, invalid JSON format

Comment: typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "ResponseDescription", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))